# Django 2.0 custom url regex

Tags: django

I had a url pattern like

```
url(r'^reset/(?P<uidb64>[0-9A-Za-z_\-]+)/(?P<token>[0-9A-Za-z]{1,13}-[0-9A-Za-z]{1,20})/$', auth_views.PasswordResetConfirmView.as_view(template_name='password_reset_confirm.html'),
```

how can I use this as new `path` pattern

Answer (score 14, accepted):

In [`django.contrib.auth.urls`](https://github.com/django/django/blob/2.0/django/contrib/auth/urls.py) the view is included as

```
path('reset/<uidb64>/<token>/', views.PasswordResetConfirmView.as_view(), name='password_reset_confirm'),
```

Comment: Thank you a lot, you saved me some hours. And could you kindly recommend the source where I can learn from about the theory/rules of such types of url-to-path converting?

Comment: @kokserek sorry, I don't have any specific sources. Searching for *url to path django* brought up this [cheatsheet](https://consideratecode.com/2018/05/02/django-2-0-url-to-path-cheatsheet/) which you might find useful. Note you don't have to switch to `path()` - you can switch `url(...)` to `re_path(...)` and keep on using regexes for existing URL patterns.

Answer (score 4):

Use re_path instead of url.

```
from django.url import re_path

re_path(r'^reset/(?P<uidb64>[0-9A-Za-z_\-]+)/(?P<token>[0-9A-Za-z]{1,13}-[0-9A-Za-z]{1,20})/$', auth_views.PasswordResetConfirmView.as_view(template_name='password_reset_confirm.html'),
```

https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.0/ref/urls/

Comment: I want to know how to use path function. I saw documentation for re_path.

Answer (score 1):

you can use regex using the new path pattern: `re_path()`. If you want to just use `path()` [create your own custom converter](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.0/topics/http/urls/#registering-custom-path-converters), for example:

```
class TokenConverter:
    regex = '[0-9A-Za-z]{1,13}-[0-9A-Za-z]{1,20})'

    def to_python(self, value):
        #code here

    def to_url(self, value):
        #code here
```

then you can use that in your urlconf

Comment: Thanks. Can u please elaborate what will be in to_python and to_url